# Thymeleaf Template Engine Bean ignored

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Application, but my Config for Thymeleaf is completely ignored. What am I doing wrong? I need Thymeleaf to process external Javascript files, but without a working Config I cant add a Javascript Templateresolver.

I know that its not working because Thymeleaf tells me that HTML5 mode is deprecated, but as you can see I set the mode to HTML.

```
package de.xy;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EntityScan("de.xy.model")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Config

```
package de.xy.config;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ITemplateResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("de.xy")
public class ThymeleafConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        engine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        return engine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Working Config:

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static final String UTF8    = "UTF-8";

    private ApplicationContext  applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver htmlViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine(htmlTemplateResolver()));
        resolver.setContentType("text/html");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding(UTF8);
        resolver.setViewNames(new String[] { "*.html" });
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver cssViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine(cssTemplateResolver()));
        resolver.setContentType("text/css");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding(UTF8);
        resolver.setViewNames(new String[] { "*.css" });
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver javascriptViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine(javascriptTemplateResolver()));
        resolver.setContentType("application/javascript");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding(UTF8);
        resolver.setViewNames(new String[] { "*.js" });
        return resolver;
    }

    private TemplateEngine templateEngine(ITemplateResolver templateResolver) {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        return engine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return resolver;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver cssTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/css/");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.CSS);
        return resolver;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver javascriptTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/js/");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.JAVASCRIPT);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

JavascriptController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("js")
public class JavascriptController {

    @RequestMapping("somejavascriptfile.js")
    public String getJS() {
        return "somejavascriptfile.js";
    }}
```

It is more than I need, but it works (Controller does nothing)

Comment: I have various other Config classes in the package de.xy.config that work perfectly (Like Datasource Beans)

Comment: Why you do not follow the standard spring boot project's organization, i-e put all static content in resources folder even thymeleaf files? And if this dependency `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` is in your classpath, Spring boot manages itself to configure the view resolver to use thymeleaf.

Comment: I thought i was following the standard spring boot project's organization... i have my html files in src/main/resources/templates, and all js and css files in src/main/webapp.

Comment: In Spring Boot standard organization all js, css and images files should be under /resources/static. You can override this if you want but it's preferable to follow standardization

Comment: So if i now have my js and css files in /resources/static/js and /resources/static/css, how to allow them to get requested? Until now i was using resourceHandlerRegistry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/"). Do i need a controller with request mappings for every static file?

Comment: Ok, i removed all my Config classes (especially the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter which was doing the Rescource Handlers) and now my static resources are available via /js/somefile.js. But I still have the Problem that i need the JS Files to get processed by Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 0):

I usually register my static contents like this :

```
@Override
protected void addResourceHandlers( ResourceHandlerRegistry registry ) {
    registry.addResourceHandler( "/js/**", "/css/**", "/images/**" ).addResourceLocations( "classpath:static/js/", "classpath:static/css/", "classpath:static/images/" );
}
```

You do not need to define again a new controller.

**EDIT**

And in Thymeleaf, example to include css files :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/styles.css}" />
```

Comment: And how to get these files processed by Thymeleaf?

Comment: See the edit, it's for css but for js files should be the same.

Comment: I need things like this inside my js files: var somePath= /* [[@{/js/file.js}]] */"/js/file.js;"

Comment: You want to get the path of your static content  in your script? As these are `static`I assume they will not varie so you can add them manually.

Comment: it is varying on the server... for example: example.com/myapp/js/file.js  or example.com/application/js/file.js. And for the future it would be nice to know, how to add modelattributes to javascript files

Comment: The variable part is this `example.com/myapp/` not the end part so you can get dynamically which varies with the javascript's `location` object and compose your url.

Comment: I moved my dynamic JS files to WEB-INF/js and added a controller for these files + a new Thymeleaf TemplateEngine bean to process these files. This seems to work. I need Thymeleaf anyway in some Javascript files so the [[@{...}]] is easyer than composing my url with javascripts location.

Comment: Could you post the code of your solution. It's important for other users.